# (UK) Should I look to buy a "better" (more expensive) flat or house now, or save/invest instead, to buy later?

Tags: investing, mortgage

I bought a flat in 2016 for £160,000. I recently (in 2024) had it valued at £210,000, so in nearly 8 years it has appreciated by about 3.5% annually. `((210000/160000)^1/8 -1) * 100`. I could afford a mortgage to buy somewhere larger and nicer, although my (back of envelope) calculation suggests that with stamp duty, solicitors fees, estate agent fees, removal fees and so on, I am looking at a cost of maybe £7000 or more to move.

Obviously the housing market may move up and down, and in the UK is at a relatively low point currently. However, I reckon I would be highly likely to make more money than 3.5% over a few years by investing in a stocks and shares ISA, and won't have additional interest to pay on a mortgage. I hope to remain in the same city, so I expect/assume that the value of my current property will vary by a similar amount as a new one I might buy.

So by my reckoning, I *might* be better off financially by investing money for a few years and then having more money to put towards a purchase. I am aware that investment returns are not guaranteed, but am planning to invest in passive trackers; if there is a crash, I will obviously have to wait and hope for a recovery. In these few years, I will not be paying additional interest on a bigger mortgage, but will instead (all being well) be earning interest towards being able to put more cash down.

I have about 20 years until I retire, and don't expect I will be able to or will want to get a mortgage much beyond that.

If I defer moving, I obviously won't have the enjoyment of a new property during that time. There is no urgent need to move.

Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no general answer; depends on your needs and wants and how you value things and what else you would do with your money. Bigger/better house will cost you more in taxes, and may or may not cost you more in maintenance, and means you aren't investing in other ways. Beware of being house-rich but cash-poor. Beware of buying more than you will actually use and enjoy.

Comment: but does it make more financial sense to delay a purchase to save more money?

Comment: When yo purchase anything depends on how much value you place in getting the item earlier vs. what you expect your savings/investments to do while you wait vs. what you expect prices to do while you wait..